# Editing Facebook test user profile

Tags: facebook-login

I don't know if I'm missing something, but I have created a test user for my app that uses Facebook login and I cannot edit any of the profile information. Our app pulls in work and education history so I want to add these to the test user to fully test the integration.

Here is an example of what I'm seeing:
[image: Add test work info]
[image]

I hit similar things on other areas. When I click on "Add a college" it just does nothing.

There seem to be a lot of errors happening including a 500 when I click on "Add a college".
[image]

So my questions are:

1. Is all of this just not really supported for test users? That would be odd to me
2. Is all of this some sort of terrible Facebook bug that I should be reporting to them? Hard to believe.
3. Am I doing something odd?
4. Is there any other reasonable way to test work/education history?

I need to submit my app for review including a screen cast of the functionality, so I'd obviously like to use a test user instead of my own account with all of my info. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently test users can only have a name, password, and friends. You can see this in the Facebook API for test user:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/test-user

Vs. an actual user:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

I'm not sure of a way to test this without logging in as yourself and getting friends to try it. You should definitely beta test it before submitting it for review though.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I spent a lot of time in the documentation and it really wasn't obvious what should and shouldn't work. Also just a very confusing experience being able to log in as the user and a random subset of functionality works and everything else throws odd errors.